# udev only reports events for a USB device configuration, not for the USB device itself

Tags: linux, usb, arch-linux, udev

I'm trying to execute a certain Python script on USB devices insertion. I need to handle all kinds of USB devices. I'm using a rule like this:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/.../test.py $devpath"
```

When I insert a USB flash drive, the `test.py` script is not executed. If I use a rule like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/.../test.py $devpath"
```

I catch events for the `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0`, which is the default configuration of the device; but I don't get any events for `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.2`. I do see such events with `udevadm monitor`, though. Why does it happen? Am I missing something?

My distro is current Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem. It turned out to be caused by a VirtualBox rule that overrode my own rule.